# Eliminar datos duplicados de un array en c#

Tags: c#, array

Por ejemplo tengo mi array:

```
int[] A = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 4 };
```

y quiero eliminar todos los duplicados y me quede de resultado un array:

```
int[] A = {1, 3, 9, 4 };
```

el distinct solo deja uno de todos los duplicados:

```
int[] B = A.Distinct().ToArray();
```

pero yo quiero que se borren todos los que se repiten.

GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayudandote con `linq` por medio del `group by` podrias ver cuantas veces se agrupa un valor y aplicarle un filtro

Algo como esto

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] A = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 4 };

        int[] B = (from item in A
                   group item by item into g
                   where g.Count() == 1
                   select g.Key).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", B.ToList()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando Linq es sencillo, podes agrupar, y luego contar la cantidad de elementos en cada grupo, de tal manera, que si tiene sólo 1 elemento, implica que no tiene repetidos, por ende, sólo seleccionaríamos esos..

```
int[] A = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 4 };

int[] B = 
            //Agrupo..
            A.GroupBy(x => x)
            //En caso de que el grupo tenga sólo 1 elemento
            .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
            //Selecciono su Key (el entero)
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            //Convierto a Array.
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Gracias!! Funciona